# Compute specific eigenvalues in the complex plane with Feast?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, lapack

In physical problems, it's quite common that we need to solve for specific eigenvalues in the complex plane, e.g. with a positive real part and negative imaginary part. In this case, we are looking for eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors in the second quadrant.

I am curious if the [FEAST algorithm](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~polizzi/feast/) could deliver faster and more accurate results for this kind of problem (dense as well), with respect to solving the full problem using `GEEV` routine from LAPACK and do the sorting explicitly.

Does anyone have experience or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The key component of using FEAST algorithm for computing eigenvalues is specifying an appropriate *search contour*. In FEAST, the user can specify circular or elliptical contours (in the newest versions, also custom-shaped ones, which can be important for targeting specific eigenvalues of non-Hermitian problems).

Now, if the size of the contour is too large (not even talking about semi-infiniteness), one would require a very large number of contour points (thus, significantly sacrificing the computation speed). For the whole quadrant, additional issues arise as one has to make a contour finite somehow (probably using some crude estimates for eigenvalue locations).

Limiting the search space to **only a quarter of the complex plane** (2nd quadrant) does not seem enough to justify using Feast algorithm. I don't see the benefits of using FEAST for computing all eigenvalues that lie in the whole quadrant – a more restrictive *search contour* is required.

References: [FEAST Manual. Section 2.1 The FEAST algorithm; Section 4.2 & 4.3 Defining a search contour](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4031)